# Jquery отличие между prop() и data()

Tags: javascript, jquery

В чем отличие в Jquery между prop и data? Можно же просто prop('blabla', value) использовать зачем data()?

Дополню: если нужно сохранить какую либо инфо в элемент, то лучше prop или data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`.data`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) позволяет получить значение дата атрибута и закэшировать его во внутреннем объекте. Не позволяет установить *атрибут*.

[`.prop`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) устанавливает значение конкретного свойства элемента.

Если нужно просто хранить какую-то информацию, то лучше использовать `data`.

Comment: Когда-то это кэширование меня здорово достало. Лишняя функция на фоне "уже давно пора на пенсию, но хотим ещё подрыгаться" ИМХО.

Comment: @Other а можно подробней в чем была проблем? Может мне data() тоже не подойдет? В чем была сложность кэширования?

Comment: @bsbak, дело было не в сложности, просто мне не нужно было кэширование, а оно было.

Answer (score 0):

```
elem.data('property-name') аналогично elem.prop('data-property-name')
```

Вот и все отличия

Comment: на самом деле не аналогично

Comment: @Grundy В чем моя ошибка?

Comment: в том, что data - берет значения из дата атрибута, но сохраняет это значение в свой внутренний объект. `prop` не берет значения из атрибутов, он берет значения из свойств. Просто добавь в свой ответ сниппет, демонстрирующий что эти вызовы действительно аналогичны