# Отличия attr() и prop() в JQuery?

Tags: jquery, веб-программирование, phpstorm, веб-дизайн

Есть два свойства, attr и prop, и я никак не могу понять чем они отличаются, если вы знаете, то напишите пожалуйста.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Jquery отличие между prop() и data()](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/595406/jquery-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b4%d1%83-prop-%d0%b8-data)

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/attributes-and-custom-properties

Comment: [Разница между prop () и attr ()](https://toster.ru/q/443806)

Answer (score 5):

Допустим нам нужно узнать, нажат ли `input="checkbox"`.
Насколько мы знаем, чтобы он был "нажат" изначально, нужно дописать ему атрибут `checked`.

Значит, нам нужно проверить его на атрибут..
Вот тут и нужно знать, чем отличается [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) от [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).

Создадим `<input>`
И проверим его на "нажатие" при помощи `.attr()`

```js
$('#check').bind('change',function(){
    var check = $(this).attr('checked');
    console.log('Check? '+check);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.js"></script>

<input id="check" type="checkbox">
```

А теперь, проверим при помощи `.prop()`

```js
$('#check').bind('change',function(){
    var check = $(this).prop('checked');
    console.log('Check? '+check);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.js"></script>

<input id="check" type="checkbox">
```

Comment: все верно, attr() - работа с текстовыми атрибутами, prop() - булевые свойства