# Jquery Как выбрать активный элемент option, в сгенерированном списке

Tags: javascript, jquery

Столкнулся с проблемой, что если список option как то изменить, то selected не работает. Пример моего кода:

```
<select>
  <option selected data-group="first" value="test1">test1</option>
  <option data-group="first" value="test2">test2</option>
  <option data-group="second" value="test3">test3</option>
</select>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        var groups = {};

        //собираем элементы по группам
        $('option[data-group]').each(function(i, el) {
          var group = $(el).data('group');
          if (!groups.hasOwnProperty(group)) groups[group] = [];
          groups[group].push(el);
        });

        //оборачиваем в новый тег
        for (var group in groups) {
          $(groups[group]).wrapAll('<optgroup label="' + group + '"/>');
        }

    });
</script>
```

Данный код разбивает option по группам, и все работает, но! Почему то selected при этом сходит с ума. И выбирается рандомно, хотя при просмотре исходного кода, селектед прописан у одного элемента, на деле он выбран другой. Почему такое может происходить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не знаю это баг или фича метода wrapAll(). Когда он оборачивает option, он теряет на каком именно option  был selected. Может не очень красивое но решение:

```js
let groups = {};
        //собираем элементы по группам
$('option[data-group]').each(function(i, el) {
   let group = $(el).data('group');
   if (!groups.hasOwnProperty(group)) 
      groups[group] = [];
      groups[group].push(el);
   });
  let saveSelected = $("select").val(); //сохарняем значение select
        //оборачиваем в новый тег
 for (let group in groups) {
  $(groups[group]).wrapAll('<optgroup label="' + group + '"/>');
}
$("select").val(saveSelected); //устанавливаем старое значение
```

```html
<select>
  <option selected  data-group="first" value="test1">test1</option>
  <option data-group="first" value="test2">test2</option>
  <option  data-group="second" value="test3">test3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вроде всё работает нормально, если не учитывать тот факт, что консоль ругается на `$('option[selected=*]').attr('selected', 'selected').parent().focus();`

Стоит забыть про такой велосипед `.attr('selected', 'selected')` и т.п., так как есть `.prop()` ([Отличия attr() и prop() в JQuery?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/843330/221218))

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var groups = {};

  //собираем элементы по группам
  $('option[data-group]').each(function(i, el) {
    var group = $(el).data('group');
    if (!groups.hasOwnProperty(group)) groups[group] = [];
    groups[group].push(el);
  });

  //оборачиваем в новый тег
  for (var group in groups) {
    $(groups[group]).wrapAll('<optgroup label="' + group + '"/>');
  }

  $('select option').each(function(){
    if($(this).prop('selected'))
    $(this).focus();
  });

});

$('select').bind('change',function(){
  //$(this).prop('selected');
  var res = $(this).val();
  console.info(res);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option selected data-group="first" value="test1">test1</option>
  <option data-group="first" value="test2">test2</option>
  <option data-group="second" value="test3">test3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: В вашем же примере, выбран первый элемент а на деле второй: https://prnt.sc/ki39sa

Comment: Хм.. Действительно..