# Как работать с data-* аттрибутами?

Tags: javascript, jquery

У меня есть в цикле ссылки у ссылок дата аттрибуты, к примеру data-date, data-title и т.д.

Мне нужно по клику на ссылку, чтобы данные этой же ссылки брались и вставлялись куда мне нужно, но это не работает. Как исправить?

```
jQuery(function($){
              $('.email__button-click').click(function(){
                let email = $(this);
                //let email = document.getElementById( 'email__button-click' );
                id = email.dataset.test;
                alert(id);
              });
            });
```

Где закомментировано, работает. т.к. указываю класс в ручную, а когда использую this, отказывается работать. Выдает ошибку test, т.е. название дата data-test

Comment: document.getElementById - это не класс, а id. Кликаете Вы по элементу с классом, а хотите получить значение data-аттрибута у элемента с аналогичным id. очевидно this и не срабатывает

Answer (score 2):

Обращайтесь к data-атрибутам через метод [data](https://api.jquery.com/data/)

Пример:

```js
jQuery(function($) {
    $('.email__button-click').click(function() {
        let email = $(this);
        let text = email.data('test') + ", " + email.data('email') + "\n\n" 
            + email.data().test + ", " + email.data().email;
        alert(text);
    });
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 
<div class="email__button-click" data-test="Hello World!" data-email="@email">Click me!</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `.data` не совсем связан с data-атрибутами

Comment: @Grundy, не нашел подтверждения вашему комментарию, плюс на enSO ответ соответствует моему: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5309947/5909792

Comment: [data - берет значения из дата атрибута, но сохраняет это значение в свой внутренний объект.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/595415/186999)